# How do I reference values in an List, excluding the current element

Tags: c#, .net, xna

So this is something that should be easy to get around but I can't quite figure out. (I'm using XNA for Visual Studios 2015. I know it's a bit outdated)

What I have is a List of Enemies (from an Enemy class). Each enemy is assigned a collision rectangle, and if one enemy intersects another enemy's collision box, they stop moving. 
I'd like to use something similar to a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < spawnAmount; i++)
{
    if (enemies[i].collisionRect.Intersects(enemies[].collisionRect))
        enemies[i].allActive = false;
}
```

So in the blank space (where enemies[] should have a value), is there any way to use all of the values from the enemies List (i.e enemies[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) *minus* enemies[i]? Otherwise the enemy detects its own collision box and stops anyway. It doesn't have to be confined to a few lines but the less complicated the better.

Answer (score 2):

Nested loops...

```
for (int i = 0; i < spawnAmount - 1; i++)
{
   for (int j = i + 1; j < spawnAmount; j++)
   {
       if (enemies[i].collisionRect.Intersects(enemies[j].collisionRect))
       {
           enemies[i].allActive = false;
       }
   }
}
```

So you start going through enemies. Let's say spawnAmount is 5.

So for `i = 0`, you compare `0 -> 1`, `0 -> 2`, `0 -> 3` and `0 -> 4`.

`i = 1`, you compare `1 -> 2`, `1 -> 3`, `1 -> 4`

`i = 2`, you compare `2 -> 3`, `2 -> 4`

`i = 3`, you compare `3 -> 4`

You don't need to compare any for `i=4`, because you'll have covered them all anyway, and because for each iteration you start `j` at `i+1`, they will never be the same anyway.

Comment: One other small optimization might be to ignore enemies who are already inactive in the second loop: `if (!enemies[i].allActive) continue;`

Comment: @RufusL - If you did that you might need to go through j from 0 -> spawnAmount for each i - depending on whether an inactive enemy can cause another to stop? Without seeing more context it's difficult to know...

Comment: I meant inside the `j` loop - it only bypasses the need to check for any more collisions if we've already stopped this guy. But if there is other code that's missing, then I see what you mean. And I meant `break` instead of `continue`. :)

Comment: Wait, you are only setting `enemies[i].allActive`, but not `enemies[j].allActive`. Let's say only `1` and `2` intersect (in your example above). The code you have only stops `1`, but `2` will stay active...

Comment: Essentially, yes. If they both stopped, they'd never continue again so it's best to have one stop (think of it as the enemy being polite and letting the other go first). Also, with this example, aren't you only checking the elements after the current Enemy? All of the enemies are on screen at once, so does this still cover the enemy hitting all others? Or just the ones that were spawned after it?

Comment: I interpreted the requirements differently because the op said "they" stop, not "he" stops. But your way makes sense

Comment: @Seamus - you ask 'aren't you only checking the elements after the current Enemy'? The answer is yes - because you have already checked the ones previous. Unless there's something in your logic whereby checking the bounding box from x -> y is different than the same check for y -> x. It's not common, though.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `Except` LINQ extension (from `System.Linq`).

The only catch is that you need to pass it a collection, so your code would be something like:

```
Enemy[] exclusionList = new Enemy[1]; //Construct outside of loop for efficiency
for (int i = 0; i < spawnAmount; i++)
{
    Enemy currentEnemy = enemies[i];
    exclusionList[0] = currentEnemy;
    if (enemies.Except(exclusionList).Any(e => e.collisionRect.Intersects(currentEnemy.collisionRect))
        enemies[i].allActive = false;
}
```

You might be able to replace the for loop entirely with some clever LINQ, and should also consider adding far away enemies to the exclusion list, as you obviously aren't colliding with *them*.

@MattWhitfields answer is actually more efficient, as this code will comare enemy 1 to enemy 0 **and** vice versa, which is definitely not required. You could build a more clever exclusion list to accommodate this problem, or use the for loops he describes.

Comment: Just one thing - for XNA, in general, you want to avoid allocations - and this will allocate a new enumerator object each time it's run.

Comment: @MattWhitfield I'm aware of the allocation restriction, but have never had an issue with enumerators/foreach. It is certainly possible to become an issue though.

Comment: If you are concerned about allocations, it is best to avoid LINQ.  For a discussion of this, see [Roslyn code base - performance lessons (part 2)](http://mattwarren.org/2014/06/10/roslyn-code-base-performance-lessons-part-2/) and [Optimising LINQ](http://mattwarren.org/2016/09/29/Optimising-LINQ/).